# How to set three letters of seven strings and some would be empty

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textview

I have a method that get some values of my `preferences` and show in a `TextView` in the screen. This `preferences` are set up in a `listview`. The user can set between 1 and 7 days of the week and when select one in the `checkbox`, the name of the day is set in his preference. If not press any `checkbox` or if the user disable the `checkbox`, I set a empty string.

My problem is that if I have more than two days select,I have to show in the `textView` only the three first letters of the day.

This is my code and that I'm trying to do.....

Thanks in advance!

```
public void refreshDays(){
        TextView listDays = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dayText);

        String monday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_MONDAY, "");
        String tuesday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_TUESDAY, "");
        String wednesday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_WEDNESDAY, "");
        String thursday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_THURSDAY, "");
        String friday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_FRIDAY, "");
        String saturday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_SATURDAY, "Saturday, ");
        String sunday = HmApplication.prefs().getString(HmApplication.PREF_SUNDAY, "Sunday");


//I'm trying to do this, but is not work....
        if(!monday.isEmpty() && !tuesday.isEmpty() && !wednesday.isEmpty()){
            listDays.setText(monday.substring(0,3) + tuesday.substring(0,3) + wednesday.substring(0,3) + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday);
        }
    }
```

And this, for example, that I want to get in the output:

```
Mon, Wed, Thu, Sat
```

PS:Note that the string that aren't in the output is because this string is empty, because the user dissable it in the checkbox that set the preference.

Comment: Not sure what you means.. My output is listDays. This is where I put the data in the screen

Comment: what do you mean by does not work. what does it show??? any erro?? if not what the values shown?

Comment: I mean that if the string is empty I have an error outOfIndex. Because I can have a empty string or a string with data

Comment: not clear. on which line you are getting error?

Comment: @Zahan. I edit my question. Is more clear now?

Comment: dont keep anything empty check all check boxes then whats the output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.....

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.append(monday.isEmpty() ? "" : monday.substring(0,3))
.
.
.
.

      listDays.setText(s);
```